# How do you calculate sum of a column without creating temp files in shell script?

Tags: shell

given an input file with data like this:

```
id,name
10,abc
20,xyz
30,def
```

I am trying to sum the values in the id column.

Note: the reason I am using awk -v header is because I have multiple files all of which have id as a common header name but at different positions.

The output I am expecting is the total sum of id (i.e., for the example above the output is 60).

The code below works and returns the expected output, but I have to create a temp file in the code and then calculate the sum.

I tried many variations unfortunately all my efforts failed.

I want to avoid writing the data to a temp file, intfile.txt, but I am stuck.

Any solutions/suggestions appreciated.

ps: I am relatively new to shell scripting and I know code is not written well, but I am working through it.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v header="id" '
BEGIN { FS=","; a=0 }
NR == 1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i==header) { a=i }} }
a=NR > 1 && a>0 { print $a }' testfile.txt>intfile.txt
awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' intfile.txt
```

Comment: Embedding a big awk script is hardly doing things "in shell script" -- you might as well have your shell script just call a Python interpreter. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

target="id"   # the field you want to sum
target_idx=   # the column number of that field
sum=0         # the sum that was found so far

{
  # first, just read the header...
  IFS=, read -r -a header
  for idx in "${!header[@]}"; do  # and look for the target field in it
    [[ ${header[$idx]} = $target ]] && { target_idx=$idx; break; }
  done
  [[ $target_idx ]] || { echo "ERROR: No $target field found" >&2; exit 1; }

  # then, iterate over other lines
  while IFS=, read -r -a line; do
    sum=$(( sum + ${line[$target_idx]} ))
  done
} <testfile.txt

echo "$sum"
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/MOnpFM

---

Some references:

- The basics of reading a file line-by-line by calling `read` repeatedly are covered in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- Fancy array syntax (including the [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) `"${!array[@]}"` to iterate over indices) is covered in [the bash-hackers' page on arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays), [BashFAQ #5](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005), and also [the BashGuide array page](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).
- Arithmetic syntax (`$(( ... ))` for math) is covered in the bash-hackers' wiki at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr

Comment: Thank-you for your time. quick question how do I pass my input file name to the script mentioned

Comment: Personally, I'd just take out the `<testfile.txt` from inside the script and connect the input to stdin; thus, invoking it as `./yourscript <"$realInputFileName"` (assuming `realInputFileName` is a variable that holds, well, the input file's name).

Comment: ...actually, if you're no longer doing redirection inside the script, you don't need the `{` and `}` at all (since all they do is scope that redirection, such that stdin comes from the file within that block).

Comment: Thanks Charles Duffy the code works. I had to comment out the line [[ $target_idx ]] || { echo "ERROR: No $target field found" >&2; exit 1; }
for some reason i was getting echo not found. Now I will try to go through the code line by line and try to understand it to the best of my ability.

Comment: Can you reproduce that not-found error on an online interpreter (like how I have an example where you can see the code working at http://ideone.com/)? Anyhow, let me know if you have questions that aren't covered in the references section and I'll add more links as appropriate.

Comment: In the mean time there is this strange thing happening I used the same code as you did and tried to reproduce the output you got in ideone.com for some reason last line in the stdinput is being skipped. But your code did work on other online terminal's plus best part I actually semi understood how to use a variable with quotes without quotes etc only part I do not at all understand is whats the purpose of  ! in the "${!header[@]}"  and $idx has the value in  ${header[$idx]}  and index position in $idx  any how thanks for the time https://ideone.com/VeiKVw

Comment: Notably, it's `|`s instead of `,`s separating the header there -- that's a different format than what was shown in the question. And as a peculiarity of ideone.com, make sure there's a newline after the last line in the "stdin" field.

Comment: I will try to reproduce that same error and post it as early as possible

Comment: yes but if you see my input i used | also the last line is getting skipped even if i used a comma.

Comment: Yes, that's my point -- if you want the code to work right with `|`, you need to change `IFS=,` to `IFS=',|'` before the first `read -a`.

Comment: ...and to fix the last line, just add a blank line at the end (it's a bug in ideone.com, not an issue with the real code: It appears to have been written by Windows people, who think of newlines as *separating* lines, but on UNIX, newlines *terminate* lines, and a line without a newline character after it isn't valid).

Comment: https://ideone.com/YtpAih
sorry i pasted wrong link but yeah that must be a bug cuz I can get output in other terminals thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
idline=$(grep id input.txt)
IFS=',' read -ra elem <<< "$idline"
idfld=0
for i in "${elem[@]}"; do
    idfld=$(($idfld+1))
    if [[ "$i" = "id" ]]
    then
        break;
    fi
done
gt=0
for num in `cat input.txt|grep "^[0-9]"|cut -d"," -f${idfld}`; do
    gt=$(($gt+$num ))
done
echo $gt
```

Comment: Thanks but this would not work in my case as I do not know which field/position id column would be.

Comment: Hi this is the error i am facing when i try this                                        
warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `$idline')          I think its because of some un printable characters or the online bash terminal I am using. i will try it out tomorrow when i go to office and revert back to you.Thanks for the time

Comment: Sorry for the delay @sam yes your script works it gave an error saying cut starts at position 1 so i made some changes but it works thanks.